# Setting seq_trace on another process

Tags: erlang, elixir, lfe

I understand that I can set a seq_trace in erlang to the current process that is executing.  But how can I set it on another process from the shell, or remote shell like dbg tracing?

Comment: Sorry--why did you tag this with Elixir?  Is there some element of Elixir here that I'm missing?

Comment: Unashamed tag jacking, primarily.  Erlang tools work for elixir as well, so anyone using them in elixir could answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable sequential tracing on another process using `dbg`. For example, let's say we have a module `x` with an exported `call/2` function:

```
call(Pid, Msg) ->
    Pid ! {self(), Msg},
    receive      
        {Pid, Reply} -> Reply
    end.
```

This function implements a simple call-response. Let's also say we have a module `y` that has a looping receiver function:

```
loop() ->
    receive
        {Pid, Msg} ->
            seq_trace:print({?MODULE, self(), Pid, Msg}),
            Pid ! {self(), {Msg, os:timestamp()}};
        _ -> ok
    end,
    ?MODULE:loop().
```

This function expects a message of the form sent by `x:call/2`, and when it receives one it prints a message into the sequential trace, if enabled, and then sends the original message back to the caller augmented with a timestamp. It ignores all other messages.

We also need a function to collect the sequential trace. The recursive `systracer/1` function below just collects `seq_trace` tuples into a list, and produces the list of `seq_trace` messages when asked:

```
systracer(Acc) ->
    receive
        {seq_trace,_,_,_}=S ->
            systracer([S|Acc]);
        {seq_trace,_,_}=S ->
            systracer([S|Acc]);
        {dump, Pid} ->
            Pid ! lists:reverse(Acc),
            systracer([]);
        stop -> ok
    end.
```

Let's assume our `systracer/1` function is exported from module `x` as well.

Let's use our Erlang shell to set this all up. First, let's spawn `y:loop/0` and `x:systracer/1`:

```
1> Y = spawn(y,loop,[]).
<0.36.0>
2> S = spawn(x,systracer,[[]]).
<0.38.0>
3> seq_trace:set_system_tracer(S).
false
```

After spawning `x:systracer/1` we set the process as the `seq_trace` system tracer. Now we need to start `dbg`:

```
4> dbg:tracer(), dbg:p(all,call).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,28}]}
```

These `dbg` calls are pretty standard, but you can feel free to vary them as needed especially if you plan to use `dbg` tracing during your debug session as well.

In practice when you enable sequential tracing with `dbg`, you typically do so by keying on a particular argument to a function. This enables you to get a trace specific to a given function invocation without getting traces for all invocations of that function. Along these lines, we'll use `dbg:tpl/3` to turn on sequential trace flags when `x:call/2` is invoked with its second argument having the value of the atom `trace`. First, we use `dbg:fun2ms/1` to create the appropriate match specification to enable the sequential tracing flags we want, then we'll apply the match spec with `dbg:tpl/3`:

```
5> Ms = dbg:fun2ms(fun([_,trace]) -> set_seq_token(send,true), set_seq_token('receive',true), set_seq_token(print,true) end).
[{['_',trace],
  [],
  [{set_seq_token,send,true},
   {set_seq_token,'receive',true},
   {set_seq_token,print,true}]}]
6> dbg:tpl(x,call,Ms).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1},{saved,1}]}
```

Now we can call `x:call/2` with the second argument `trace` to cause sequential tracing to occur. We make this call from a spawned process to avoid having shell I/O-related messages appearing in the resulting trace:

```
7> spawn(fun() -> x:call(Y, trace), x:call(Y, foo) end).
(<0.46.0>) call x:call(<0.36.0>,trace)
<0.46.0>
```

The first line of output comes from normal `dbg` tracing, since we specified `dbg:p(all, call)` earlier. To get the sequential trace results, we need to get a dump from our `systrace/1` process:

```
8> S ! {dump, self()}.
{dump,<0.34.0>}
```

This sends all sequential trace collected so far to our shell process. We can use the shell `flush()` command to view them:

```
9> flush().
Shell got [{seq_trace,0,{send,{0,1},<0.47.0>,<0.36.0>,{<0.47.0>,trace}}},
           {seq_trace,0,{'receive',{0,1},<0.47.0>,<0.36.0>,{<0.47.0>,trace}}},
           {seq_trace,0,{print,{1,2},<0.36.0>,[],{y,<0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,trace}}},
           {seq_trace,0,
                      {send,{1,3},
                            <0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,
                            {<0.36.0>,{trace,{1423,709096,206121}}}}},
           {seq_trace,0,
                      {'receive',{1,3},
                                 <0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,
                                 {<0.36.0>,{trace,{1423,709096,206121}}}}},
           {seq_trace,0,{send,{3,4},<0.47.0>,<0.36.0>,{<0.47.0>,foo}}},
           {seq_trace,0,{'receive',{3,4},<0.47.0>,<0.36.0>,{<0.47.0>,foo}}},
           {seq_trace,0,{print,{4,5},<0.36.0>,[],{y,<0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,foo}}},
           {seq_trace,0,
                      {send,{4,6},
                            <0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,
                            {<0.36.0>,{foo,{1423,709096,206322}}}}},
           {seq_trace,0,
                      {'receive',{4,6},
                                 <0.36.0>,<0.47.0>,
                                 {<0.36.0>,{foo,{1423,709096,206322}}}}}]
```

And sure enough, these are the sequential trace messages we expected to see. First, for the message containing the `trace` atom, we have the send from `x:call/2` followed by the reception in `y:loop/0` and the result of `seq_trace:print/1`, then the send from `y:loop/0` back to the caller of `x:call/2`. Then, since `x:call(Y,foo)` is called in the same process, which means all the sequential tracing flags are still enabled, the first set of sequential trace messages is followed by a similar set for the `x:call(Y,foo)` invocation.

If we just call `x:call(Y,foo)` we can see we get no sequential trace messages:

```
10> spawn(fun() -> x:call(Y, foo) end).
<0.55.0>
11> S ! {dump, self()}.
{dump,<0.34.0>}
12> flush().
Shell got []
```

This is because our match spec enables sequential tracing only when the second argument to `x:call/2` is the atom `trace`.

For more information, see the [`seq_trace`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/seq_trace.html) and [`dbg`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) man pages, and also read the [match specification chapter of the Erlang Run-Time System Application (ERTS)
User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html).